# Instead of displaying output after each iteration in my for loop, how to I get my program to display all outputs at once in java

Tags: java, swing, for-loop, joptionpane

I am new to coding and I wanted to know how can I code it so that I get the input question asked 3 times and then have my output displayed altogether in one message box. I want it to be kind of like:

Person 1's name is a

Person 2's name is b

Person 3's name is c

```
package example;

import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class Example {
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        for (int a =1; a<4; a++){
            String name = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Enter person " + a + "'s name");
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Person " + a + "'s name is " + name);
        }
    }
    
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Declare a StringBuilder before for loop.

> StringBuilder names = new StringBuilder();

Append each name inside loop with a suitable separator.

> names.append("Person ").append(a).append("'s name is ").append(name).append("\n");

Then show the message dialog outside for loop with concatenated StringBuilder value